# validator undefined

Tags: jquery-validate, validation

I used jQuery validator and bound it to a click event like this :

```
var validator = $("#formId").data('validator');
```

When I click the first time I load the page I get the error "validator undefined", but when I refresh the same page it starts working.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:
I use jQuery mobile and I had to turn the ajax off like this :

```
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
```